# How to reorder / sort profiles in Firefox

Tags: firefox

Recently I have been more and more using profiles in Firefox.

I have one for every member of the family, then some for proxied firefoxes (tor, i2p, freenet), then a "guest" default profile, and several profiles for development purposes.

Soooo, profile management starts to become important. And the very first problem I have, is to reorder them, for instance in this order :

```
Personal
Girlfriend
Children
Dev1
Dev2
Dev3
Testing
Freenet
Tor
etc ...
```

So, is there an addon, a trick to have that ordering ? I guess the other way round is to use gnome / mate, etc. menu options to start those profiles and manage them from there. But I'm now looking for a Firefox-only solution.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, after testing many addons, I found a way to reorder my profiles. It is not in an addon (should be main feature in Firefox, but anyway...).

The trick is to edit your `profiles.ini` file. It is located, in linux, in `~/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini`.

First, backup:

```
cp ~/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini ~/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini.bak
```

Second, edit:

```
vim ~/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini
```

You can then copy and paste the lines in order to have this the order you want :

```
[General]
StartWithLastProfile=1

[Profile0]
Name=Default
IsRelative=1
Path=fhsdjsufh.Default
Default=1

[Profile1]
Name=Myself
IsRelative=1
Path=dfhfkvldk.default

[Profile2]
Name=Children
IsRelative=1
Path=kfmfpoernv.Children

[Profile3]
Name=Friends
IsRelative=1
Path=fjvovbswk.Friends
```

I don't know if this is the best way, but it works. Please care to keep the formatting and titling as they are, just copy the lines between the `[Profilex]` titles.

Source : [Mozillazine](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profiles.ini_file?)

Answer (score 1):

I also use a lot of profiles. I use MozBackup to backup a base profile
with addons I like. I restore that base onto profiles I later create using
the popup when I run `firefox.exe -P -no-remote`.

I haven't found a way to sort the profile list in that popup in either Firefox
nor MozBackup so I wrote a python script that sorts the entries by name in `profiles.ini`.

I'm on Windows but I use the Linux subsystem with Debian flavor to run this script.
To install python 3.6:

```
apt-get install curl git build-essential zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev
curl https://pyenv.run | bash
pyenv install 3.6.8
pyenv local 3.6.8
```

Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6

import configparser
import re

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.optionxform = str
# this option is mandatory as list in popup will be blank
# if we let configparser default to lowercase option key.
config.read('profiles.ini')

nconfig = configparser.ConfigParser()
nconfig.optionxform = str
nconfig['General'] = config['General']

profiles = [section for section in config.sections() if re.match('^Profile', section)]
sorted_profiles = sorted(profiles, key=lambda profile: config[profile]['Name'])

for idx, profile in enumerate(sorted_profiles):
    # 2020-08-25 - fixed this line which was generating syntax error
    nconfig["Profile" + str(idx)] = config[profile]
    # dict are sorted in python 3.6
    # it seems profiles don't need to be renamed,
    # but let's fake we created them in order anyway.

with open('profiles.ini.new', 'w') as f:
    nconfig.write(f, space_around_delimiters=False)
```

Comment: This is a great script but had a syntax error in line 20 `nconfig[f"Profile{idx}"] = config[profile]`. Seems fixed now. Works great!